# Method used in v-for loop doesn't return value

Tags: vue.js

I'm rendering a list of objects with titles. Titles are sorted and I want to add before every next title which starts with new letter of the alphabet heading with given letter.

In `v-for` loop I include method `azTitle` with `itemTitle` parameter. In the method I first check if first letter of given title is included in `azTitles` array. If not, then I push given first letter into `azTitles` array and then I return first letter as a heading for group of titles with the same starting letter.

```
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in videos">

    {{ azTitle(item.title) }}

    <p>{{ item.title }}</p>

</div>

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
           azTitles: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        makeAzTitle(title){
            return title.substring(0, 1);
        },
        azTitle(itemTitle){ 

            if (!this.azTitles.includes(this.makeAzTitle(itemTitle))) {

                this.azTitles.push(this.makeAzTitle(itemTitle))

                return "<h2>"+this.makeAzTitle(itemTitle)+"</h2>"

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The result I expect is this:

A
Anthony
Andrew
B
Bethany
E
Emily
Emma
...

but I get this:
Anthony
Andrew
Bethany
Emily
Emma
...

Why the method doesn't render values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate data like that in a loop. What I'd do instead is use `v-show` on the `h2` element and check if it needs to be displayed or not.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in videos">
  <h2 v-show="isFirstTitle(index)">{{ makeAzTitle(item.title) }}</h2>
  <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
</div>
```

```
methods: {
  makeAzTitle(title){
    return title.substring(0, 1);
  },
  isFirstTitle(index){ 
   if (index === 0) {
     return true;
   }

   if (this.makeAzTitle(this.videos[index].title) !== this.makeAzTitle(this.videos[index - 1].title)) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work.

Vue only accepts `expressions` in the [template syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions). Your function declaration is not an expression and as such it doesn't work.

Your best bet is to use `v-if` or `v-show` and use a method as the value for those.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is the wrong way to achieve it. Unfortunately, I can't explain to you why its not working but I can show you a better way to do what you want.

You should take your collection of videos and let them be sorted inside a method to a object of this style:

```
{
    A: [
        { title: 'Andrew' },
        { title: 'Alex' },
        { title: 'Alduin' }
    ],
    B: [
        { title: 'Bread' },
        { title: 'Butter' }
    ],
    E: [
        { title: 'Emma' },
        { title: 'Ernst' }
    ]
}
```

Then you can loop it properly this way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    videos: [{
        title: 'Andrew'
      },
      {
        title: 'Alex'
      },
      {
        title: 'Alduin'
      },
      {
        title: 'Bread'
      },
      {
        title: 'Butter'
      },
      {
        title: 'Emma'
      },
      {
        title: 'Ernst'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    categorizedVideos() {
      let cv = {};

      for (let i = 0; i < this.videos.length; i++) {
        let video = this.videos[i];
        let category = video.title.substring(0, 1);

        if (!cv[category]) {
          cv[category] = [];
        }

        cv[category].push(video);
      }

      return cv;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(videos, key, index) in categorizedVideos()">
    <h2>{{ key }}</h2>
    <div v-for="video in videos"> {{ video.title }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```